# Data Structure that supports in functions at o(log n)

Tags: data-structures, avl-tree

Data Structure S that supports at this functions

bulid(s)      - build S from n keys    O(n*log(n))

INSERT(x,s)   - insert key x to S      O(log n)

DELETE-MAX(S) - delete the max key     O(log n)

DELETE-OLD(S,t) - delete the OLD-t key  (t Symbolizes the order of insert)   O(log n)

ADD-TO-NEW(S,D) - add to the last key the value d O(log n)

i was thinking on avl tree , and int lastKey (for ADD-TO-NEW function ) , but i didnt find solution to Delete-Old function .

Comment: I guess you could use two avl trees that reference each-other. One sorted by value, the other sorted by insertion order. But it's a bit annoying and boring. Probably they're looking for a smarter answer than that.

Comment: i  thought on two avl tree , but i need to update the insert order, after delete.